# Show that the only nonzero ideals of R are the principal ideals $\langle p^e \rangle$

Tags: number-theory, ideals

> Let $p$ be a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $R = R_p = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}\ |\ \textrm{ord}_p(x)\geq0\}$, which is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> Show that the only nonzero ideals of $R$ are the principal ideals $ \langle p^e \rangle$ for $e \geq 0$.

No idea on how to answer this. The definition is clear, but I do not think I have to use it.

Comment: Yeah that's the basic local field.  You have to show that for any other prime $q$ you have $\langle q\rangle=R$.  It's the most basic theorem in local fields you must be able to look that up somewhere.

Comment: I mean think about it, for $q\not=p$ you have $\frac1q\in R$ so obviously its ideal is all of $R$.

Comment: No idea what a local field is. How would I make what you said more formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\langle r_1,r_2,\dots\rangle$ be an arbitrary ideal in $R$.  Let $e=\max_i ord_p(r_i)$.  Then for all $i$ $r_i=p^e s_i$ where $s_i\in R$.  Thus $r_i\in\langle p^e\rangle$ for all $i$.  Thus $I\subseteq \langle p^e\rangle$.  Now let $i$ be such that $ord_p(r_i)=e$.  Then
$r_i=rp^e$ where $r\in\Bbb Q$ and $ord_p(r)=0$.  Thus $r$ is a unit in $R$ because also $\frac1r\in R$.  Thus $p^e=\frac1r r_i$. Thus $\langle p^e\rangle\subseteq\langle r_i\rangle\subseteq I$.  And since we also showed $I\subseteq \langle p^e\rangle$ it follows that $\langle p^e\rangle=I$.

Thus all ideals are of the form $\langle p^e\rangle$.

Comment: In all fairness I guess I haven't shown every ideal is principle.  Just that every principle ideal is of the form $\langle p^e\rangle$.  Let me think about the principle part and edit my answer.

Comment: I have $x=p^e \frac{a}{b}$ where $p$ does not divide $a,b$ as a starting point.

Comment: @George I completely changed my answer I think it's complete now.